# arange elements on user interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

On a webapp, I have to give to the user, the option to arange some elements, as she whiches. I'm looking for a client-side tool. ATM, the user can modify the orders of elements, by pushing some up,down buttons, which save to the db, the current order index.

it has to e a better way. Gmail use something to drag and drop elements in order to arange them, but I don't know how is made, and where to start from in order to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Would recommend Jquery-UI's sortable.

See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#placeholder

Very crossbrowser secure, theme-able and extendable and easy to use.

Also alot of threads and tutorials around :)